# Xgboost node splits on a value that out of feature range?

Tags: xgboost

I have some features that range from 0 to 1.
But when I dump the model, I find some nodes split those features using "feature < 2.00001". 
Does xgboost scale the feature or add some value to the feature? Or why 2.00001 is chosen to split?
Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

xgboost has separate splits based on values of the feature and whether or not the feature is missing.

This is usually when xgboost wants to split only on whether or not the feature is missing, and not based on the value.